# How to store Multiple list of objects in room - Android

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have a doubt about creating tables for my network response.
My network response will be like:

```
    data class ProductsList(
        val next: String? = null,
        val perPage: Int? = null,
        val previous: String? = null,
        val count: Int? = null,
        val results: Results? = null
    )
```

```
    data class Results(
        val prices: List<PricesItem?>? = null,
        val products: List<ProductsItem?>? = null
    )
```

```
    data class ProductsItem(
        val image: String? = null,
        val content: List<Int?>? = null,
        val prices: List<Int?>? = null
    )
```

I'm confused the I should have one table or many tables. I'm beginner to room and SQL so if you have any resource to learn more about the room and data handling that will be very helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use @Relation to create wanted object, which contains whole data https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542

Comment: Thank you, but it is a network response and I don't have Common ids. so how I will use @relation